# Can someone parse this sentence?

Tags: interpretation

The sentence is "This was the first time the provision of services in general through Irish by the state system was placed on a statutory footing."
I just saw this sentence on a list and it doesn't provide any context. What do "in general", "through Irish", "by the state system" describe? Do they describe the provision or the services or the first time? Please try to give an easy explanation.

Comment: Please include more context. This is a quote from Wikipedia, and we need for you to **edit the entire short paragraph into your question** (there's an 'edit' link underneath it) to understand what is meant there.

Comment: It's rather clumsy phrasing, but *services in general* means ***most** services* (of various types, not limited to particular *kinds* of services). And *through Irish* means *through the medium of (**using**) the Irish **language***. The State system just means using the mechanisms of government and civil servants (usually one would just say "the State", but here we're specifically focusing on the *infrastructure* system used by the State to perform its duties on behalf of the citizenry).